# Using tf.data.Dataset in keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a model written in Keras. Because I'm dealing with large files, I'm using tf.data.Dataset api to load data and feed into the Keras fit function. Before I call model.fit(), I reinitialize the dataset using it=ds.make_initializable_iterator() and then pass the X, and y tensors that I get from the it.get_next() function to the model.fit(). The problem is that, when model.fit() reaches the end of the dataset, it does not continue training, in other words, I can only train for ONE epoch, not matter what I pass as the "epochs" variable to the fit function.
How can I tell Keras to reinitialize the iterator when it reaches the end of the dataset?

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `dataset.repeat(n_epochs)` to repeat your dataset for the number of epochs.

The `epochs` argument in the `model.fit` function defines how many times to iterate over the dataset. If you do not repeat the dataset, however, you will run out of samples after the first epoch. You can use `dataset.repeat(n_epochs)` to repeat for `n_epochs`, or you can use `dataset.repeat()` to repeat infinitely.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is, I don't know upfront how many batches exist in my tfrecords, Keras fit does not know when one dataset epoch is finished, it just goes by the number of steps_per_epoch that I give, and to know that I need to know the size of the dataset, which is not possible unless I start iterating over tfrecs once, and count!

Comment: In more recent version of tensorflow, i have noticed that you can give a dataset that repeats multiple epochs and not provide `steps_per_epoch`. the `fit` function will then count the number of steps in the first epoch on its own.